# Finding sub intervals from interval data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals, intersection

I have two `data.frame`s with coordinates of linear intervals, which correspond to ids. Each id has several linear intervals. One of the `data.frame`s is called `exon.df`:

```
exon.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("id1",4),rep("id2",3),rep("id3",5)),
                      start=c(10,20,30,40,100,200,300,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000),
                      end=c(15,25,35,45,150,250,350,1500,2500,3500,4500,5500))
```

And the other `cds.df`:

```
cds.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep("id1",3),rep("id2",3),rep("id3",3)),
                      start=c(20,30,40,125,200,300,2250,3000,4000),
                      end=c(25,35,45,150,250,325,2500,3500,4250))
```

They both have the same ids but the intervals of `cds.df` are contained within those of `exon.df`. The intervals in `exons.df` are exons of genes (parts of the genome which are copied and stitched together to make a transcript of the gene), and those in `cds.df` are the parts of these exons that will be translated to protein since exons of the gene transcript also contain parts that will not be translated (Un-Translated Regions - utr). These utr's can only be located at the start and end of the gene transcript. The utr in the start is called 5'utr and the utr in the end is called 3'utr. A utr may either not exists at all, or span anywhere between part of a single or more exons from each end of the gene.

This means that the 5'utr of an id starts from the id's first position of its first interval in `exon.df` to one position before its first interval in `cds.df`, and includes all the exons in `exon.df` in between if such exist. Similarly, the 3'utr of an id starts one position after its last interval in `cds.df` to the last position of its last interval in `exon.df`, and includes all the exons in `exons.df` in between if such exist.
It's also possible that an id will not have either or both utrs if the first position of its first interval in `cds.df` is its first position in its first interval in `exon.df`, and similarly if its last position of its last interval in `cds.df` is its last position in its last interval in `exon.df`.

I'm looking for a fast way to retrieve these 5'utr and 3'utr intervals give `exon.df` and `cds.df`.

Here's what the outcome for this example should be:

```
utr5.df <- data.frame(id=c("id1","id2","id3","id3"),
                     start=c(10,100,1000,2000),
                     end=c(15,124,1500,2249))

utr3.df <- data.frame(id=c("id2","id3","id3"),
                     start=c(326,4251,5000),
                     end=c(350,4500,5500))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/)? It's an add-on for R, specifically for the biosciences. It has a package called [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html), with which you can create a GRanges object that contains all Exons, and another object that contains all CDSs.

You can then do a *set difference* of these two objects to get the UTRs. Check the section "setops-methods" [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/GenomicRanges/man/GenomicRanges.pdf). You want the 'setdiff' function.

So: Transform your data.frames into GRanges objects, then issue something like `utrs <- setdiff(exons, cds)`

Comment: Thanks. setdiff is the correct function for getting the UTRs

Comment: Oh, right, you need setdiff, sorry. I said 'intersect' . I updated my answer.